# How to feed the output of TfidfVectorizer to the LinearSVC classifier in Sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a linear classifier using `LinearSVC` in Scikit learn. I decided to use the tf-idf vectorization for the purpose of vectorizing the text input. The code I wrote is:

```
review_corpus = list(train_data_df['text'])
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df = 0.9,stop_words = 'english')
%timeit tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(review_corpus)
```

I now want to train an SVM model using this tfidf_matrix and use it to predict the class/label for the corresponding test set: `test_data_df['text']`.
The problem(s) I'm having:

1. Is it correct to use only the training data to build the TfIdfVectorizer or should I use both the training and testing text data to build the vectorizer?
2. The main issue is: How do I get the matrix representation for the testing data? Currently, I'm not sure how to get the tfidf score from the vectorizer for the different documents in the test set. What I tried was to loop through the Pandas series `test_data_df['text']` and then do:

   ```
   tfidf_matrix.todense(list(text)
   ```

for each text in the Series, put the result into a list and finally make a numpy array out of it but I get a Memory Error.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use only the training data to build the `TfIdfVectorizer()`. This will ensure that you are not leaking any information about the test data during training process.
2. Use

   ```
   tfidf_matrix_test = vectorizer.transform(test_data_df['text'])
   ```

Now you can feed the `tfidf_matrix_test` to the classifier.

P.S.:

Try to avoid casting the sparse_matrix output of the Vectorizer to list or dense array. Because it is memory intensive and classifier will also take more computation time while training/prediction.